# Azure guest user access issue

Tags: azure, botframework, bots

I am running a webapp on Azure. This app is a botservice whats connecting to Cortana. When I logged in with original account which I creted the Azure portal its works but if I try use the app with an other ms account (ofc I added the account in azure ad as a guest user and gave it GA).

Tried to remove the account and add it back again - desnt help.
Tried to add it as a co - admin - doesnt helped at all.
Tried to add to Access control (IAM) as an owner - doesnt helped.
Tried to add ti Access control (IAM) in the app services - doesnt helped.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue, however, Cortana channels are owned by the developer that created them and adding other developer MSAs to IAM will do nothing.  If you need a Cortana channel deleted, contact skillsup at microsoft dot com with the botid (name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cortana Skills can be shared with other users either by "Publish to group " or "Publish to world". You could create a group and then invite users to join the group to be able to access the skill.
Please go through the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/mva71-share-skill

If not shared , the skill will be accessible only to the developer who created the skill.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found that. It was unclear that I have to click test group setting to show, this is a weird design.